# Missing fonts folder on jekyll deploying to netlify

Tags: jekyll, netlify

When deploying jekyll project to netlify I am missing my fonts folder.

It works perfectly find when in development mode but when I tell it to run in production it seems to skip over adding my fonts folder to the _site/assets directory.

I believe it has to be something in the config but I am fairly new to jekyll and YAML. And in the code its seems to be saying to add all the assets underneath it to the build process.

Below is my _config.yml file.

```
copy:
  # Paths to static assets that aren't (S)CSS or JavaScript
  # because these are completely handled by the sass and javascript tasks
  assets:
    # all files below the assets dir
    - "assets/**/*"
    # exclusions:
    - "!assets/{js,scss,css}/**/*"   # js, scss and css files
    - "!assets/css{,/**}"            # css dir
    - "!assets/js{,/**}"             # js dir
    - "!assets/scss{,/**}"           # scss dir
    - "!assets/vendor{,/**}"         # vendor di
  dist: "_site/assets/"
  notification: "Running Copy"
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format multiline code.

Answer (score 4):

Note:  I work for Netlify

While I'm not sure of the fail mode here, I can tell you a couple things that would help you debug:

1. the easiest way to debug a build is described in this article:  https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/  .  This lets you duplicate our build environment in a way that you can access during/after the build so you can see what is happening or has happened in more depth than our build logs
2. If you write into support we can set a verbose flag on your builds that does the equivalent of 'set -x' on the building shell script to show you what's being run in production, though filtering this output is quite a task for a human, it may be more useful than nothing!